# How can I put a succeeding values into another table while inside of a cursor?

Tags: sql-server

How can I achieve this , I wanted to collect all of the counts in one place.

```
-- 1 - Declare Variables
-- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(50) -- table name 
DECLARE @inst VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ctr INT

-- Initialize Variables
-- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
SET @table_name = N'tblTranslate' 



-- 2 - Declare Cursor
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
-- Populate the cursor with your logic
-- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
SELECT idauctionsite FROM #pastauction 

-- Open the Cursor
OPEN db_cursor

-- 3 - Fetch the next record from the cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @inst  

-- Set the status for the cursor
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
 
BEGIN  
    -- 4 - Begin the custom business logic
    -- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
    SET @sql = N'SELECT COUNT(*) as cout FROM' +' '+ +'dbo.' +CAST(CONCAT(@table_name,@inst) AS VARCHAR(50))
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    


    -- 5 - Fetch the next record from the cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @inst 
END 

-- 6 - Close the cursor
CLOSE db_cursor  

-- 7 - Deallocate the cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

This script returns multiple results row/grid.

I wanted to put all the cout in something like temporary table but I'm currently stuck because I use dynamic query.

Comment: *"I'm currently stuck because I use dynamic query."* You can still `INSERT` the result set from `sys.sp_executesql` into a table. The fact that it is used to execute (dynamic) SQL doesn't stop the operation.

Comment: @Larnu does this mean I can execute multiple query while using sp_executesql?

Comment: `sys.sp_executesql` executes the entire batch you pass it. If that batch contains many statements, then yes, it'll execute many statements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a cursor, nor to insert the data into a temporary table. You can just create a `UNION ALL` style query dynamically, then execute it.

```sql
-- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(50) = N'tblTranslate' 

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(pa.idauctionsite, '''') + ' AS idauctionsite, COUNT(*) as cout
FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name + pa.idauctionsite)
      AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL'
      )
    FROM #pastauction pa
);

PRINT @sql; -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

On earlier versions of SQL Server, you can't use `STRING_AGG` so you have to hack it with `FOR XML`

```sql
-- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(50) = N'tblTranslate';

DECLARE @separator nvarchar(100) = N'
UNION ALL';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = STUFF(
    (
    SELECT @separator + '
SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(pa.idauctionsite, '''') + ' AS idauctionsite, COUNT(*) as cout
FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name + pa.idauctionsite)
      
    FROM #pastauction pa
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(@separator), '');

PRINT @sql; -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: this returns 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: That's because you are on an older version of SQL Server, have modified

Answer (score 0):

@Larnu is suggesting something like this:

```
DECLARE @results table(inst varchar(50), cout int)
BEGIN  
    -- 4 - Begin the custom business logic
    -- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
    SET @sql = N'SELECT '+@inst+' as inst, COUNT(*) as cout FROM' +' '+ +'dbo.' +CAST(CONCAT(@table_name,@inst) AS VARCHAR(50))
    insert into @results
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    


    -- 5 - Fetch the next record from the cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @inst 
END 

select * from @results
```